# AWS: SCP to an EC2 instance via AWS CLI without public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a linux instance on AWS without a public IP address.

I know how to connect to it via the AWS CLI

```
aws ec2-instance-connect ssh --instance-id <INSTANCE_ID> \
  --private-key-file <PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY> --connection-type eice
```

How can I copy files from my local machine to my AWS instance? Usually I would use `scp`, however I do not have a public IPv4 address. How can I do this via the AWS CLI?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This looks like it's a feature request https://github.com/aws/aws-ec2-instance-connect-cli/issues/1 (the very first feature request)

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use [Port Forwarding Using AWS System Manager Session Manager | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/). This allows you to forward a port when connecting via Session Manager (instead of EC2 Instance Connect). If you forward port 22, then you could run `scp` over it.

Comment: Or, the simpler version: Copy files from the instance to S3, then download from S3.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein does using port forwarding as described in that link strictly require a running bastion host? Because that does incur an additional cost which is not there when using ec2-instance-connect

Comment: @apokryfos no bastion needed

Comment: AWS Systems Manager Session Manager uses an 'agent' installed on the instance to establish an outbound connection to the AWS Systems Manager service. This means that instances in private subnets can be accessed, as long as there is a NAT Gateway to reach the Internet or a 'VPC Endpoint for Systems Manager' to reach the Systems Manager service. Yes, it's quite confusing. There are some good YouTube videos from AWS on the topic: [How do I make VPC endpoints to use Systems Manager to manage private EC2 instances without internet? - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNheLwttAdc)

Answer (score 1):

ec2 instance connect doesn't have the scp component. You could either use [AWS systems manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html)

OR

you need to login the aws network using vpn or Directconnect

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a private IP with EC2 Instance Connect, you'll need to have an EC Instance Connect Endpoint configured that can access that private subnet. Once this is the case, you can do as follows.

First, send your publish SSH key to the instance:

```bash
aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key \
  --instance-id INSTANCE_ID \
  --instance-os-user INSTANCE_USER \
  --ssh-public-key "$(cat path/to/ssh/key.pub)"
```

Then, use `aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel` as a proxy for the `ssh/scp` command:

```bash
scp -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h' \
  SRC... INSTANCE_USER@INSTANCE_ID:DEST
```

Note that after the `send-ssh-public-key` command, the public key is only available for 60 seconds, after which if you need to run a new SSH command, you'll need to send it again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try and do the `scp` using the below command, if it works then enjoy.

```
scp -i <PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY> /path/to/local/file ec2-user@<PRIVATE_IP>:/path/to/destination/directory
```

You need to establish your ssh connection first using the command you posted and then run `scp` and make sure to replace the required values.

Comment: Alas, connecting to the Private IP address won't work from the Internet.